# How to get the position of text using 'PDF-Reader' gem in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, selenium, pdf-reader

I am new to Ruby and we are using Ruby Selenium framework for automating the PDF verification testing.
I want to verify the content of PDF, like text and also get the position of the text. Along with that I also need to get the text at a given position.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe

```
require 'pdf-reader'
require 'open-uri'
reader = PDF::Reader.new(open("SAMPLE_URL")) # my resume pdf
page = reader.pages.first
lines = page.split("\n")
text_match_line_numbers = [0...lines.length].select do |i|
  lines[i] .include? "text"
end
```

Look at their docs [here](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader), there are more advanced options for navigating the PDF page.